# How to show the inspector within your WKWebView based desktop app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit, wkwebview, webkit2

I'm looking for a way to show the [inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH1-SW1) for a WKWebView inside my Mac app.

With WebKit1 and WebView it was easy to show the inspector inside your Mac app, by just setting WebKitDeveloperExtras to true in your UserDefaults. That would give you an "Inspect Element" menu in every web view.

But in WebKit2 with WKWebView this is not working anymore. In the WWDC14 inspector session they explain that you have to add an entitlement and can then show the inspector from the Safari developer menu. This only works if you are the developer.

I looked through the [private headers](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebViewPrivate.h) and found _allowsRemoteInspection which makes me think you can somehow launch an inspector and connect to it, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Although I'm hoping for an official way to do this, my app is not in the AppStore, so I'm ok with using private stuff.

Comment: Although I don't have an answer to your question, I do know what the _allowsRemoteInspection is likely to do.  If you open Safari and go to the Develop menu, you'll see a number of devices (iPhone, etc) that allow you to remotely debug webpages on a device or simulator.  So I don't think this is the property that you're looking for to provide in-app inspector behaviour.

Comment: The other workaround is to create an Applescript to launch Safari browser with Developer menu and package this script within the app. When needed you can invoke this script from your App.

Comment: I need to the same thing for iOS.

Comment: @GuidoMB did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was patched here: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2014-August/026790.html

Just expose the private property like this and you can use it.

```
@interface WKPreferences (WKPrivate)
@property (nonatomic, setter=_setDeveloperExtrasEnabled:) BOOL _developerExtrasEnabled;
@end
```

Now you get the "Inspect Element" menu on right click.

The only thing I still need to find out is how to show the inspector directly from code.

Comment: Got it going for Swift, see answer below.

Comment: I also got it going for Swift, just using Key-Value Coding. No bridging headers required.

Comment: @KoenBok Have you found out how to show the inspector directly from code?

Answer (score 33):

For Swift, instead of building a bridging header you can set it directly

```
self.webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")
```

Comment: that is like steak on the grill mmmmmm

Comment: I submitted a Feedback Assistant report about making this functionality officially supported: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/80 Please duplicate that report if you wanna see this happen.

Comment: Is there a way to open the inspector window automatically?

Answer (score 19):

Based on what Koen found, an easier way to set this property is to use Key Value Coding, no bridging headers required.

Swift:

```
let preferences = webView.configuration.preferences
preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")
```

Or in Objective-C:

```
[webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"developerExtrasEnabled"];
```

Key Value Coding will look for methods and instance variables that match the key, including private ones prefixed by an underscore.

Comment: What object is preferences from?

Comment: `webView.configuration.preferences`

Comment: So i've enabled developerExtras, but how do i then access the info. For example, I load a webpage... and now I'm trying to access the Network activity and print out the results...

Comment: no api into it afaik

Answer (score 6):

## isInspectable

Starting on **macOS Ventura** (`13.3`), there is a new property [isInspectable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/4111163-isinspectable) on `WKWebView`; turning it on will enable the inspector. No need to rely on private APIs or `KVO` anymore.

```swift
wkWebView.isInspectable = true
```

#### Warning

There is a caveat tho, to show the inspector, you need to right-click on a website, and the context menu should have the option `Inspect Element`. Sometimes this is not the case, and you need to open the **Web Inspector** from **Safari** (developer tools need to be enabled on Safari).

```
Safari > Develop > [Name of your device] > [Name of your app] > [URL or title of website open with WKWebView]
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Koen Bok's answer, for Swift, confer [this gist](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/39e47f4579fd9526273f). Using those files, you'll need to add the following line to your bridging header:

```
#import "WKPreferences+DevExtras.h"
```

Usage looks like

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: window.frame)
webView.configuration.preferences.enableDevExtras();
```

Comment: I used this approach in my Swift project, but I get `-[WKPreferences enableDevExtras]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000006d40` and the webView is staying empty. Any ideas?