# WKWebView load local content with LoadFileUrl

Tags: c#, xamarin, wkwebview, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to load a local html file in a WKWebView with the LoadFileUrl method, but all I get is a blank view. It's a **Xamarin.Mac** App (no Sandbox yet).

```
WKWebViewConfiguration conf = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
WKWebView www = new WKWebView (View.Frame, conf);
View = www;

string index = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebApp/Index.html");
string webAppFolder = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebApp");

www.LoadFileUrl (new NSUrl ("file://"+index), new NSUrl ("file://"+webAppFolder));
```

Loading a webpage from a remote server with "LoadRequest" works just fine.

Build Action for the "Index.html" file is "BundleResource"

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8

Comment: @Gusman thanks, but I already saw the link, if I got it right, "LoadFileUrl", should be the solution, but it doesn't work!
Is it perhaps still buggy on ElCapitan? Should I copy the html file in the "temp" folder and load it from there?

Comment: It should load, better see the webview inspector and see if there is any error when loading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200116/how-to-show-the-inspector-within-your-wkwebview-based-desktop-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris Hamons pointed me in the right direction on the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61891/wkwebview-load-local-content-with-loadfileurl#latest).
Just changing

```
string index = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebApp/Index.html");
string webAppFolder = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebApp");
```

to

```
string index = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath, "WebApp/Index.html");
string webAppFolder = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath, "WebApp");
```

did the trick!

Comment: You can select your answer as solution then :-)

Answer (score 5):

For those not using Xamarin and fighting with loadFileURL: for hours(like me).

When you are moving the web folder to a project, select "Create folder references"

[image]

Then use code that is something like this:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString("/WebApp/index.html"){
  let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
  if let webAppPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString("/WebApp") {
    let webAppUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: webAppPath, isDirectory: true)
    webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: webAppUrl)
  }
}
```

In the html file use filepath like this

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

not like this

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Example directory
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! Your sample code and screenshots helped me debug an issue I was chasing.